# "Damn am I hungry." vs "Damn I am hungry." What is the difference?

Tags: grammaticality, expressions, sentence, questions

I know this is a stupid question, but I've heard a lot of people saying some sentence like that, like interrogative sentence, but they didn't mean to ask a question.

> Damn am I hungry, lets go get some food.

and

> Damn I am hungry, lets go get some food.

Is there any difference?

Comment: "Am I hungry?" is a _rhetorical question_ - asked to emphasise a point, not because the speaker doesn't know the answer.

Comment: @KateBunting That should be an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the comma:

> Damn, am I hungry, lets go get some food.

and

> Damn, I am hungry, lets go get some food.

In either case, the expression is the same. The first one sounds more exaggerated but both convey the same idea.

Answer (score 0):

A question that is asked in order to emphasise a point or make the hearers think, and not to seek an answer, is called a [rhetorical question](https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/topics/zmfc7ty/articles/z7dyvk7).

As the other answer says, your sentences need punctuation.

> Damn [it], am I hungry! Let's go get some food.

Comment: I'd say it's a parallel construction rather than a rhetorical question. Usually, a rhetorical question is meant to prompt thinking, whereas this seems just an emphatic form (and would never employ a question mark). The article by Andersen and Aijmer does not call these inversions rhetorical questions.